# How to confirm behavior of SPDY on android webview

Tags: android, http, webview, chromium, spdy

Hi, everyone.

I am investigating behavior of SPDY on android webview.
So, could you tell me how to confirm that whether or not my webview is speaking SPDY?
I have built a customized ROM applied the following patch.

https://codereview.chromium.org/106903017/diff/20001/android_webview/browser/net/aw_url_request_context_getter.cc

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the spdy ssl off.

`net::HttpStreamFactory::set_force_spdy_over_ssl(false);`

Then using the wireshark with SPDY plugin. If you can see the SYN_STREAM/REPLY_STERAM. Congratulations, you're using SPDY now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... maybe connect it to Wifi, use Wireshark or similiar tool to capture traffic your phone generates to a selected SPDY enabled website and check if it's really SPDY compatible or not according to specs.

Answer (score 0):

With wireshark you are going to get nothing, spdy goes over ssl. Your best bet is logcat. But I think cordova uses spdy:

https://apache.googlesource.com/cordova-android/+/2.9.x/framework/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/spdy/